# React useState not updated after value is set from Props on re-render

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, use-state

**I'm new to react and using hooks**

What I want to achieve is after submit button is clicked, get the necessary expected values and then all fields will be reset to blank, by setting the states into new Object.

I was able to get the necessary values and I expect setting state values into new default object  will reset the values of the text fields but it seems I failed.

Will someone shed a light on me why this behavior happens?

BTW: using material-ui text fields

the setup is available at: https://github.com/blackmo18/react-usestate-error.git

here is my component structure:

```
<Register/>
    |
    | --> <StudentDetails/>
    |       |
    |       |
    |       | --> <PersonDetails/>
    |       |
    | - - - x --> <GuardianDetails/>
            |       |
            |       | --> <PersonDetails/>
            |       | --> <PersonDetails/>
            |
            | --> <ButtonSubmit/>
```

Pseudo code for each component:

***Data Classes***

```
Person {
    firstName
    lastName
    middleName
    .....
}
Guardian {
    father : Person
    mother: Person
}

BaseStudent {
    id: number
    person: Person
}

Student: BaseStudent {
    guardian: Guardian
}
```

**Register Component**

```js
    const [studentDetails, setStudentDetails] = useState(new Student())
    const [baseStudent, setBaseStudent] = useState(new BaseStudnet())
    const [guardian, setGuardian] = useState(new Guardian())

    const handleSubmit= (student: BaseStudent) => {
        setBaseStudent(student)
        setStudentDetails(Object.assign(studentDetails, baseStudent))
        // -- call api
        ....
        setBaseStudent(new BaseStudent())
        setGuardian(new Guardian())
    }

    const handleGuardian = (guardian) => {
        setGuardian(guardian)
        setStudentDetails(Object.assign(studentDetails, guardian)}

    }
    return (
      <StudentDetails
         onSubmit = {handleSubmit}
       >
        <GuardianDetails
           onChange = {handleGuardian}
        />

      </StudentDetails>
    )
```

**PersonDetails Component**

```js
    const {person, onChange} = props
    const [person, setPerson] = useState(person? person : new Person())

    const handleFirstName = (e) => {
        setPerson(Object.assign(person, {firstName: event.target.value}))

        handleChange()
    }
    .................

    const handleChange = () => {
        if (onChange) {
            onChange(person)
        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <TextField 
                label = 'firstName'
                deafultValue = {person.firstName || ''}
                onChange = {e => {handleFirstName(e)}}

            />
            ........
        </div>
    )
```

**Student Component**

```js
    const {onSubmit, value} = props
    const [student, setStudent] = usetState(value ? value : new BaseStudent())

    const getPerson = (person) => {
        setStudent(Object.assign(student, {person: person})
    }

    const handleChangeId = (e) => {
        setStudent(Object.assign(student, {id : e.event.target.value})
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (onSubmit) {
           onSubmit(studentDetails)
        }
    }

    return (
         <TextField
            label = 'id'
            onChange = {e => {handleId(e)}}
        />
        <Person
           person = {student.person}
           onChange = {getPerson}
         />
        <Button onClick = {handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
    )
```

**Guardian Component**

```js
    const {value, onChange} = props
    const [guardian, setGuardian] = useState(value ? value : new Guardian());
    const [mother, setMother] = useState(new PersonState(new Person()));
    const [father, setFather] = useState(new PersonState(new Person()));

    const handleMother = (personMother) {
        setMother(personMother)
        setGuardian(Object.assign(guardian {mother: mother})
        handleChange({mother: mother})
    }
    ....
    const hanldeChange = (parent) => {
     setGuardian(Object.assign(guardian, parent))
     if (onChange) {
        onChange(guardian)
     }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <PersonDetails
                person = {mother}
                onChange = {handleMother}
            />
            <PersonDetails
             ...........
            />
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to look through the code, without being able to run it, but at a first look something that might be causing your issue: In the Register component's `handleSubmit`, you're calling `setBaseStudent` then using `baseStudent` in the next line. Don't forget that setBaseStudent will not be executed synchronously, so the next line will be using the old value of `baseStudent`. Same in `handleGuardian`.

Comment: @Grabofus I added the repository, you may look at it

Comment: You also seem to have a duplicate declaration of `person` in `PersonDetails`. You're getting it from props AND setting it with `useState`.

Comment: Just had a look at the repo, first issue I found is your `GuardianPanel` components receives the guardian object as a prop, which is also reset when the api is called. However, the `GuardianPanel` component created its own state to store the guardian data, that should not be the case. Both `guardian` / `setGuardian` should be passed down as props from the parent component. I would guess the same will apply to the person details too.